# Missing toolbar in SSDT SQL Server Database Project sql file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj, sql-server-data-project

In Visual Studio 2019, when i create a new sql query file, i can see a toolbar inside the tab like this:

[image]

With SQL Server Data Tools i have created a new SQL Server Database Project with .sql files of stored procedure and functions where this toolbar is missing.
I can run the query only by the right click menu.

[image]

Is there any setting to show this toolbar on every opened .sql file?

Answer (score 2):

Adding execute and server connection to the top of the SQLQuery
You can change the properties in:
Solutions Explorer.
Right Click .SQL file
Click Properties
Build Action change it to None
close and reopen the query window.

[image: Image of what it looks like]

[image]

Comment: This was super helpful after many years again. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't this mean the file is no longer part of the build and, for example, if a column the sproc depends on is removed, the build isn't automatically going to flag this sproc as broken?